# Change the geometry of an existing layer?

Tags: qgis, geometry, geometry-conversion

I work with QGIS, v. 2.0.1. I have a point layer in which I have structures that could be represented as lines or polygons, but at the moment they are represented as a group of points. I know I can create new layers with different geometry but if I do this, I don't have the attribute table of the original point layer attached to the new line/polygon layer. And if I copy the point layer, I have the attribute table but it's not the right geometry. Can I change the geometry afterwards?

I could do a table join, right? But I don't have a common attribute and the table join is not permanent is it?

I tried the "PointstoPaths" Plugin, but it's not what I'm looking for. I also found the "Points2One" Plugin which seems perfect for my problem, but somehow it doesn't work (a shapefile is created but I can't "see" anything in the map).

That's how the map looks: for lines:

[image]

and for polygons:

[image]

I have about 800 points and the attributes show name of the place, measurements, date and much more.

Comment: The key problem you are describing seems to be that you don't have a "common attribute". If that is the case then you can only really associate the points by proximity (closeness or a specified distance). Or associate them manually. Expand on your question with more information about your data, how many points, what info is in the attributes. Also see this for a similar problem http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89122/qgis-2-0-automatic-generation-of-a-vector-layer-out-of-a-point-layer/89270?noredirect=1#comment124182_89270

Comment: Does this help? ...  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224025/how-to-convert-points-into-line-without-changing-the-attributes/224034#224034

Answer (score 1):

Creating a buffer around points (or lines) will result in a polygon shapefile that preserves the attribute table.

If you want to connect your points to a line or polygon, you have to specify the sequence of the points in the line. Form your images, I have not understood how you want to do this.

If you want to join 2 points with different attributes, only one can be stored for the line.

Comment: I just want to connect some points to a line/polygon but not all of them. For example in the first image, I want to represent the river as a line, not as many points, in the second image I want to have a polygon but at the moment I have some points that are the outline of the polygon. Can I create a buffer around a selection of points? I tried to create one but it only works for all points.

Comment: You can select points by rectangle, and click to `buffer only selected`. Or you add a column in the attribute table, give the river points a certain value, and filter the layer by that.

Comment: Ok the buffer thing is not working. What do you mean with filter the layer by that? I actually want a result like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DfdKI.png But as you can see I have two layers. The point layer has the complete attribute table and the polygon layer has just one value. Can I do something that they share the attribute table?

Comment: If your data is in degrees, you have to set a very small value for buffering. For the filter, Rightclick on the layer entry, -> Filter lets you choose a field and a value, like "name"='xyz'. Only matching features will be displayed with that, and the buffer will also be only around those points.

Answer (score 0):

For as few as 800 points and if you don't expect to be doing this anytime again soon, I would do it manually. Look in settings and turn snapping on with minimum tolerance, digitise a new line on the points. It'll be a lot more achievable.